# Angular - Using value recipe in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty new to angular and got stuck with following thing.

**Template**

```
  <div>
  <form novalidate>
     First Name:<br>
     <input type="text" ng-model="registrationdetails.firstName"><br>
     Last Name:<br>
     <input type="text" ng-model="registrationdetails.lastName"><br>
     Voucher Code:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="registrationdetails.voucherCode"><br>
    Country :<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="registrationdetails.country"><br>

 <br><br>
<button ng-click="submit()">submit</button>
```

**Service registrationdetails**

```
    registrationDetails =     
    angular.module('emailApp.registration.registrationdetails', []);

    registrationDetails.value('registrationdetails' , {

     firstName:'',
     lastName:'',
     voucherCode:'',
     country:'',
     email:'',
     password:'' 

   });
```

**Controller**

```
registrationstep1.js 

myapp.controller('registrationStep1Controller' ,       
function($scope,$state,$http,registrationdetails,registrationFactory){

 $scope.registrationdetails = registrationdetails;  ---> why it works here 

$scope.submit = function(){

    //$scope.registrationdetails = registrationdetails; ---> why it does not works here 

    firstName = registrationdetails.firstName;  ---> this contains firstName entered by user as I am expecting 
    lastName = registrationdetails.lastName;
    voucherCode = registrationdetails.voucherCode;
    country = registrationdetails.country;

    console.debug(registrationdetails);
    data = {};
    data.firstName = firstName;
    data.lastName = lastName;
    data.voucherCode = voucherCode;
    data.country = country;

    registrationFactory.step1Store(data);


    $state.go('registration.step2');

    }   

});
```

So what does  `$scope.registrationdetails = registrationdetails;` actually signify if registrationdetails is a value service.

I am confuse with this piece of code. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You already assigned the reg Details to a Scope Use that scope in submit Like $scope. registrationdetails.firstName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of how object assignment works in JavaScript.  The statement

```
$scope.registrationdetails = registrationdetails;
```

creates what is called a 'shallow copy' of `registrationdetails`.  Meaning we're dealing with pointers.

> JavaScript uses pointers for everything!  Meaning that the object you just attached to the `$scope` is really just a pointer to the same object that `registrationdetails` points to (yes, `registrationdetails` is just a pointer to an object somewhere in memory).  Now any time you update a property on one of these objects, the actual object (somewhere in memory) gets updated and **both** pointers will reflect the change.

**Now here's a (simplified) walkthrough of what your working code is doing:**

The user types 'J' in the `firstName` input field.

Angular says, "Alright, the `ng-model` directive says to update the `firstName` property of an object called `registrationdetails` on the current scope.  Ahh, here it is, and the value of `firstName` is currently `''` (empty string).  Let's add a 'J' to that."  Etc...

> Remember the pointers!  What's happening here is that angular is modifying `$scope.registrationdetails`, which is a pointer to the same object that `registrationdetails` points to.  Meaning **angular is updating both objects** (really just one object that both variables point to).

And when `submit()` is called, you have access to all the updated properties on the `registrationdetails` object, because angular has been updating them all the while (via updating `$scope.registrationdetails`) that the user was typing.

**Now here's what the non-working code is doing:**

The user types 'J' in the `firstName` input field.

Angular says, "Alright, find `registrationdetails.firstName` on the current scope.  Woops!  It doesn't exist.  Let's do the boss a favor and create that object and put a `firstName` property on it with the value 'J'."  Etc...

Now when `submit()` is called, your code is basically saying, "Hey, angular, I know you worked so hard to build that object that I foolishly forgot to put on the `$scope`.  But with this statement:

```
$scope.registrationdetails = registrationdetails;
```

I'm going to assign `registrationdetails` to this new object that I injected a while ago and is full of empty strings.  Sorry, I guess that object you sweated and slaved over will just be food for the garbage collector."

> Remember pointers?  Yeah, the `registrationdetails` pointer that angular created on the `$scope` **is pointing to a different object** than the `registrationdetails` you injected into your controller.  This assignment statement overwrites the object that angular created.

Now when you access `firstName`, `lastName`, etc... you get the empty strings on the object that `registrationdetails` has been pointing to this whole time.

Hope this helps to clear things up.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you did not define registrationFactory but trying to append data which cause failing to run app.

when you saved data to scope the scope default watches for changes.

```
   firstName = $scope.registrationdetails.firstName;   
    lastName = $scope.registrationdetails.lastName;
    voucherCode = $scope.registrationdetails.voucherCode;
    country = $scope.registrationdetails.country;
```

Updated the Code with running Plunker Please use developer tools to see the updated Submit data console  in an Object

https://plnkr.co/edit/8ULkhrqjsphDazZU8FTX?p=preview

Thanks.